# Building a dynamic query with JPA Specification and Predicate, findAll() leads to PropertyReferenceException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an API that will be taking in a date range. My application is using Redis and we have to query entries by indexed date strings. Because Redis doesn't allow a query like `Select * from Redis where date in (...)`, I have to be able to create a dynamic query with an unspecified amount of 'or' conditions to the effect of `select * from Redis where date = x OR date = y OR date = z`. I've followed [these](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications) [tutorials](https://dimitr.im/writing-dynamic-queries-with-spring-data-jpa) but of course they're extremely vague and don't actually work as advertised. I will be looking into [Querydsl](http://querydsl.com/) tomorrow to see if that's a viable option. Here's the jist of my code.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EventSpecs implements Specification<Event>{
  private ArrayList<String> dates;

  @Override
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Event> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    return builder.or(
        dates
        .stream()
        .map(value -> builder.equal(root.get("date"), value))
        .toArray(Predicate[]::new)
    );
  }
}
```

Repository:

```java
public interface EventRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Event, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Event> {}
```

and where it's being called:

```java
@Autowired
private EventRepository eventRepository;

ArrayList<String> dateRange = new ArrayList<>();
PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(0, 10);
EventSpecs specs = new EventSpecs(dateRange);

Page<Event> events = eventRepository.findAll(specs, page);
```

But when I call `findAll()` I always get
`org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type Event!`  and I understand I should be calling by class properties like `findByDate()` but I don't want to query by a static amount of parameters. Am I on the right path to accomplishing what I need to? Does anyone have resources for more thorough tutorials? [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) is the exact same way, vague and their code doesn't work either.

Comment: What makes you think a `JpaSpecificationExecutor` will work for Redis? Redis isn't JPA so that query part won't work, that is only useable for JPA. Which is also why it fails as it doesn't know how to handle that and will resort to regular method parsing to create a query.

Comment: @M.Deinum Because we use JPA for normal CRUD operations on our Redis instance.

Comment: Well the exception tells you this support hasn't been translated into the criteria API.